# Insert into a table selecting from an external list of tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic, union, sql-insert

Good morning everybody !
I have a list of tables in SQL from which i have to select a number of fields and then copying them into another table.

This list is not "fixed" since it's updated every week, so some tables are deleted and others are added.
I've already created a really easy table where i store the ID and the name of these tables.

My import procedure is very easy :

```
INSERT INTO [LIST_UNION] ([1],[2],[3]
SELECT [1],[2],[3] FROM [First_List_in_Table]
```

But what i need is to repeat this for every table of the initial list :

```
INSERT INTO [LIST_UNION] ([1],[2],[3]
SELECT [1],[2],[3] FROM [Second_List_in_Table]

INSERT INTO [LIST_UNION] ([1],[2],[3]
SELECT [1],[2],[3] FROM [Third_List_in_Table]
```

And so on.
How can i create a procedure to dinamically read these tables ID and import the fields i need one by one ?

Comment: _so some tables are deleted and others are added_ That sounds like a basic design error.